# remove homepage content using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide my homepage content after other link is clicked. My homepage content is into

```
<div class="active">
Homepage content
        </div>
```

css class active and inactive

```
.active {   
    margin-top:230px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color:black;
 }  
.inactive
{
    opacity:0;
}
```

I tried this script but it is not working.

```
   <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $("#link-link1").click(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("active").addClass("inactive");

                                        });
    </script>
```

I upload it to an web hosting so you can see full html code [here](http://skusobnastranka1.php5.sk/) and full css file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r64w2kyfm0eynj1/main.css)

Comment: Using `this` in your script will try to remove or add the classes to `#link-link1` rather than your div with the class on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an ID to the "Homepage content" div, so we can find it using javascript.

```
<div class="active" id="contentArea">
    Homepage content
</div>
```

Try placing you jQuery code inside a document read. Optionally place it right before the closing *</body>* tag. Add the css classes to the "Home content" div and not to the link element addressed by *$(this)*:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var contentArea = $("#contentArea");
    $("#link-link1").click(function(){
         contentArea.removeClass("active").addClass("inactive");
    });
});
```

Consider using the jQuery function [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) for changing contents visibility.

Take a look at the manual: http://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: Your code work for me. Without $( document ).ready(function() it is not working. Thanks

Comment: I'm pleased to hear that. Please consider marking my answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(this).removeClass("active").addClass("inactive");
```

Is adding and removing the class from your link (which I assume has `id="#link-link1`)

Instead you need to give your div an id like

```
<div id="homepage" class="active">
```

Then in your JS code reference that by id:

```
$('#homepage').removeClass("active").addClass("inactive");
```

Even better would be to use jquery's `hide()` method or `toggle()` if you wanted it to come back the next time you clicked:

```
$('#homepage').toggle();
```

Comment: Thanks it work but i have to use $(document).ready(function()

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look at that [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nd4Hf/) I make a simple example for you.
In you'r web page you must use better `div` elments as tabs not `a` elements

Code:

```
$("#random_link").click(function(){
    //$(".active").css("display","none"); //WORKS TOOO
    $(".active").fadeOut();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aPF3V/)</kbd>
**HTML**

```
<a id="link1" href="#">Hide Home Page</a>
<a id="link2" href="#">Show Home Page</a>
<br/>
<div id="home_page">
    <hr/>Homepage content
    <hr/>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#link1').click(function () {
    $('#home_page').hide();
});
$('#link2').click(function () {
    $('#home_page').show();
});
```

*Hope this helps..!!*

**Update using `toggle()` based on @Cfreak answer**
<kbd>[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aPF3V/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Jquery you can use hide method that will apply to your css of that element `display: none;`

```
$('#homepage').hide();
$('#homepage').show(); //to make it visible again
```

hope it help

Comment: while `hide()` and `show()` are better ways to do it the core problem is that `$(this)` references the wrong element

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the class for the div, in your code you are change the class of the link, add an Id or class to the div, for example:

```
<div class="active" id="test">
     Homepage content
</div>


<script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $("#link-link1").click(function(){
        $('#test').removeClass("active").addClass("inactive");

    });
    </script>
```